# Изменить условие цикла при выполнении

Tags: c#, c++, c

Не страшно же, если во время работы цикла я изменю его условие?

```
const int
    E_LOWRIDE_AROOWS_ARRAY = 30;

int
    i,
    index,
    nextIndex,
    createArrowId = 23,
    numArrows = 8;

index = createArrowId+numArrows;

index = index >= E_LOWRIDE_AROOWS_ARRAY ? E_LOWRIDE_AROOWS_ARRAY : index;

nextIndex = index-E_LOWRIDE_AROOWS_ARRAY;

for (i = createArrowId; i < index; i++)
{
    //какая-то задача

    if (i >= E_LOWRIDE_AROOWS_ARRAY)
    {
        i = 0;
        index = nextIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы может сюда писать все что душе угодно.

Comment: в приведенном куске тело цикла нигде не изменяется

Comment: ой, не тело, а условие цикла

Comment: Пока что никакого изменения тела цикла я лично не вижу... Изменения условия цикла - тоже.

Comment: Почему в тегах три разных языка? Выберите один.

Comment: Что значит "изменю условие"? Как вы собрались "изменять условие" во время работы цикла?

Comment: Если вы имели в виду переменные `i` и/или `index` в вашем примере, то да, можете изменять их в теле цикла как хотите

Answer (score 0):

> во время работы цикла я изменю его условие?

Уточнение: не условие, а значение переменной цикла и значение переменной из условия завершения цикла.

Синтаксис С такое не запрещает. Но это считается очень дурным стилем. Дело в том, что в таком случае практически невозможно, читая текст программы, понять - завершится цикл когда нибудь, или нет?

Более того, даже во время тестирования программы нет никаких гарантий того, что протестированы **все**  возможные варианты выхода из цикла.

Т.е. такую программу невозможно толком ни проанализировать, ни протестировать.

Ситуация, которую Вы показали, очень прямо намекает на то, что внутри основного цикла должен быть либо вложенный цикл, либо вызов функции, выполняющей вложенную обработку.